# Phraseology in Shmone Esrei for Shabbos Mincha

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, mincha-afternoon-prayer, nusach-ashkenaz

In the paragraph starting אתה אחד, the ideas being conveyed are all  praise to Hashem about His uniqueness, Am Yisroel and Shabbos.

It ends off however with a request.     יכירו בניך וידעו כי מאתך היא מנוחתם, ועל מנוחתם יקדישו את שמך.

Artscroll interlinear translates: May Your children recognize and know that from you is their rest, and through their rest, get will sanctify Your name. Metsudah and Koren translate similarly, but this is what I have at hand now.

My first question is the phrase ועל מנוחתם יקדישו את שמך. They are reading it as if it says ועל ידי, through. Is this a common phenomenon in nusach hat'fila? Usually על is used to mean 'on' or 'upon' such as וקדש את שמך על מקדשי שמך.

The phrase על ידי, if we are to assume this is functioning as, should be  written out in full as we find in שחרית לשבת the phrase על ידי משה עבדך.

A second less bothersome question.   The beginning of the request also seems uncommon. We don't usually run from the praise into the request without some type of dividing or connecting tool. Like a vav as is utilized in the regular weekday שמנה עשרה, or an address to Hashem like אלהינו ואלהי אבותינו as we find in the follwing paragraph.

Edit:I ust found a variant translation which at least does not translate this as a request. The Hirsch siddur has this:
Your children will realize it and they will know that such rest is theirs from You, and for their rest they will hallow Your Name.

Basically, are there any other options in translating this phrase? I would also find acceptable if you can bring enough similar usages that would prove my assumptions wrong.

Comment: We don't always separate praise and request. Consider the אתה חונן לאדם דעת ומלמד לאנוש בינה חננו מאתך, or (in the _musaf_ of Rosh Hashanah) ה' צבקות יגן עליהם כן תגן על עמך ישראל בשלומך

Comment: @Ypnypn that's true. If you don't mind though, I would differentiate and point out those are a request regarding the same point being mentioned. Here there is a brand new idea about recognition bring requested.

Comment: I don't understand your concern in the 2nd question. The middle of the paragraph already sounds like a "request" by saying "M'nuchat Ahavah un'davah ... etc." Sounds like the "request" appears much earlier in the paragraph than what you are stating, no?

Comment: @DanF that is not a request. That is mentioning the type of rest it is, a praise. Not a request That it should please be a certain type of rest.

Comment: Offhand, the ending words כי מאתך היא מנוחתם refers to the rest of the forefathers, Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob. I.e. - the reason they rested is that it was ordained by G-d, and they recognized that. Thus, the request is that the sons should recognize this fact, too. Thus, the phrase ועל מנוחתם means, "BECAUSE of their resting" not "By the means of their resting". No proof, but my best understanding.

Comment: @DanF כי מאתך comes after the request יכירו בניך. it is not the ending of the last piece concerning the avos.

Comment: I wasn't clear, I guess. what I meant was to emphasize that the term מנוחתם meaning "their rest" does not mean the children's rest. "Their" means "the forefathers' rest". Regarding use of the word על implying a meaning of "because" or "therefore", see ועל כולם and על כן נקוה לך  in the 1st case, ועל כולם , we had just completed mentioning the many miracles of G-d. So, in a sense, we say, "because of all of these miracles, we should thank you."

Comment: @DanF i actually understood what you meant:) It just really doesn't flow. Not sure if your interpretation is better or worse in my ears than the siddurim I mentioned. But thanks for the time and trouble. I've been reading this phrase over and over since shabbos afternoon when it hit me that I don't get it.

Comment: Tefillah isn't miduyak in the same manner as mikra and mishna. Poetic flow is as important to word choice as specificity of meaning (and sometimes ambiguity is poetically intentional). Your counter example (al makdishei shimecha) I have heard translated by many rabbanim as both "upon" and "through," so "al" isn't to the exclusion of "al yidei."

Comment: @Isaac regarding your first statement, see Chinuch 606 s.v. ומן הענין. Regarding your second statement, ok. Many unnamed rabbis have translated it so. The siddurim I quoted did not.